# using assert_equal and .join metho failed pass the unit testing, when learning RoR with the book Agile Development with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, assert

I just started learning Ruby on Rails, even Ruby language itself.
after reading the **Iteration B2: Unit Testing of Models** and doing the following exercise:
1. The validation option :length checks the length of a model attribute. Add validation to the Product model to check that the title is at least ten char- acters long.
2. Change the error message associated with one of your validations.

I put the following code into /models/product.rb

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title, :message => 'has already been taken'
validates_length_of :title, :minimum => 8, :message => 'must be at least 8 letters'
```

and put following cods into /unit/product_test.rb

```
test "product is not valid without a 8 letters title" do
product = Product.new(:title =>"12345678",
                      :description => "yyy",
                      :price => 1,
                      :image_url => "fred.gif")
product.title = "abcdefg"
assert product.invalid?
assert_equal "must be at least 8 letters", product.errors[:title].join('; ')
product.title = "abcdefgh"
assert product.valid?    
end

test "product is not valid without a unique title" do
product = Product.new(:title => products(:lighting).title,
                      :description => "yyy",
                      :price => 1,
                      :image_url => "fred.gif")
assert !product.save
assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors[:title].join('; ')

end
```

but when i run rake test, there's a failure i can't figure out how to solve it, it shows:

```
1) Failure:
test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title(ProductTest)
/Users/youngoo/Development/RubyonRails/anaheim/test/unit/product_test.rb:66]:
<"has already been taken"> expected but was
<"has already been taken; must be at least 8 letters">.
```

how that happen? and how i can do with it?
i thought the problem is related to the *join* method
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `assert_equal`, try using `assert_match` like this...

```
assert_match /has already been taken/, product.errors[:title].join('; ')
```

You're on the right track.

**EDIT:** If `assert_match` is to be depreciated,

```
assert_not_nil /has already been taken/.match(product.errors[:title].join('; ')
```

should yield the same results

Comment: it says, the method _assert_match_ is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. is there any substitution?

Comment: which ruby are you using? You can also use the longer work around - which I will add as an edit to my solution.